# How can I show that a r.v. with cumulative distribution is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, random-variables

I want to show that, if $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X$, then $X$ is absolutely continuous *iff* $F_X \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ ?

I know absolutely continuous means that there exists $f(x) \ge 0, \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) dx = 1$ such that $P(X \in A) = \int_A f(x) dx$, and this happens if and only if $F_X (x) = \int_{-\infty} ^ x f(t)dt$

Now, we know $F_X (x) = \int_{-\infty}^x F'_X (t)dt$, and since $F_X \in C^1$, we know that $F_X'$ exists, it must be the density and $X$ is continuous.

I am interested in a rigorous proof. Can this be considered rigorous?

Can some hypothesis be relaxed?

Answer (score 0):

The *iff* is not true:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2 \text{ if } 0\le x \le \frac {1}{4}\\ \frac {2}{3} \text{ if } \frac {1}{4}< x \le 1\\ 0 \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

$$ f\not\in C^0$$

$$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(x) dx$$

$X$ is continuous r.v.

Comment: would the *iff* be true if instead of $F \in C^1$, I request $F \in C^1$ piecewise?